# click-touch menu-navigation dropdown

Tags: jquery, html

I have googled quite a bit but have not found a solution. I hope someone can help. I have the following working code:

```
    <header data-role="header">
    <nav data-role="navbar">
        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
        <a href="autobio_overview.php">Autobiography</a>
        <a href="cooking_overview.php">Cooking</a>
        <a href="help.php">HELP</a>
        <a href="lmc_overview.php">Musical&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Drumming</a>
        <a href="horses.php">Horses</a>
        <a href="spiritual-quest.php">Spiritual/Weird&nbsp;Stuff</a>
        <a href="trains.php">Trains</a>
        <a href="webdev_overview.php">WebDev/Computer</a>
        <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
        <!--<a href="family.php">Family&nbsp;History</a> -->
        <!--<a href="favlinks.php">Favorite&nbsp;Links</a> -->
    </nav>
</header>
```

and

```
<header data-role="header">
<nav>
Cooking Pages: 
    <a href="cooking-asian_overview.php">Asian/Chinese&nbsp;Cooking</a>
    <a href="cooking-equipment-gadgets-manuals.php">Cooking&nbsp;Equipment,&nbsp;Gadgets,&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Manuals</a>
    <a href="catalog.php?tablename=cooking_videos">
        Cooking&nbsp;Video Collection</a>
    <a href="cooking-favorite-restaurants.php">Favorite&nbsp;Restaurants</a>
    <a href="cooking-nonasian_overview.php">Non&#8209;Asian&nbsp;Cooking</a>
    <a href="cooking-cookbooks_old_downloadable.php">Old&nbsp;Downloadable&nbsp;Cookbooks</a>
    <a href="cooking-tea-coffee_overview.php">Tea&nbsp;&amp;&nbsp;Coffee</a>
<br>
<span class="red center">Cookbook/Book and Audio/Video Collection links may take a little time to load, please wait!</span>
```

and these work just fine with each producing a single line on a desktop. But I would like to replace

```
<a href="cooking_overview.php">Cooking</a>
```

with a dropdown Cooking box/button which when clicked/touched would display the second header as a single dropdown line immediately below the Cooking box/button. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the cooking pages as a list under the cooking link in the header.  Then have the list as hidden.  Then show it when clicked.  I used something similar to this.

```
<a href="cooking_overview.php">Cooking</a>
<ol> 
<li><a href="cooking-asian_overview.php">Asian/Chinese&nbsp;Cooking</a></li>
<!--with the rest of the menu options-->
<ol>
```

Then I used css to hide/show the list.

```
ol li {
  display: none
}
ol li:clicked {
  display: block
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: thanks, but I want to display the second header menu below the Cooking button essentially as it now is written when the new Cooking button is clicked...not go to the Cooking link.

Comment: I know how to do it with lists. I want it to show the second line of links below the first line of links.

Comment: I actually tried the above suggestion and it does not display as needed.